# Internet Explorer and drop-down list issue

Tags: angular, html, angular5, internet-explorer-11, html-select

I have a `<select>`dropdown with a long list of `<optgroup>`. The dropdown is created as a separate component in Angular5 and it does some processing before segregating into `<optgroup>`. 

The long segregated list displays properly in `Chrome` but only partially in `Internet Explorer`. I checked the HTML source and saw the full list of HTML coming properly.
 The list is partially displaying properly and rest getting inserted as blanks. I can still select and made sure the value is present but not rendering in UI.

Note: No console errors. Not sure what is the issue. Screenshot for IE below:
[image]

Comment: _Screenshot or it didn't happen!_ Surprised to find such an issue! Wow.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman screenshot attached

Comment: see the blanks after the last `<optgroup>`

Comment: Oh wow... Thanks Arun...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I believe its something regarding angular change detection. When I inspect the source and dragged one option to another all options got displayed

Comment: Bro, I really feel it's something to do with IE... LoL. `:(`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps to make sure your angular application is supported on internet explorer:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help.